# Not enough input arguments when calling GA toolbox

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I called Matlab's genetic algorithm solver, `ga`, in the following way:

```
[theta,fval,exitflag] = ga(smmobj,26,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],[]);
```

where theta is a *26*-by-*1* column vector that needs to be optimized.

So in the main function, it goes like this:

```
clc
clear
global var1 var2...
load ('abcd.mat')
theta0=[1 2 3....];
LB=[26-by-1 row vector];
UB=[26-by-1 row vector];
[theta,fval,exitflag] = ga(smmobj,26,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],[]);
```

The fitness function, *smmobj*, is defined as:

```
function [obj]=smmobj(theta)
    global var1 var2...
```

But when I run it, it always says:

> ```
> Error using smmobj (line 4)
> Not enough input arguments.
>
> Error in SMMga (line 32)
> [theta,fval,exitflag] = ga(smmobj,26,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],[]);
> ```

But I run the fitness function by itself, it works.

Comment: Add a `@` before `smmobj`. And try checking search results next time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[theta,fval,exitflag] = ga(smmobj,26,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],[]);
```

will throw that error because you are essentially calling the function `smmobj` (with no parameters) instead of passing your `ga` function a [*function handle*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html) to your objective function. You do this using the `@` symbol so

```
[theta,fval,exitflag] = ga(@smmobj,26,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],[]);
```

Incidentally, I would recommend that you do not use `global` in order to pass the extra parameters of `var1` and `var2` to your objective function but rather use [*anonymous functions*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html?searchHighlight=anonymous_function):

```
[theta,fval,exitflag] = ga(@(x)(smmobj(x,var1,var2)),26,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],[]);
```

and then change `smmobj`'s definition to

```
function [obj]=smmobj(theta,var1,var2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dan! It works! May I ask what is the advantage of using anonymous functions over global variables? It seems to me that using global functions is clearer. I can tell which are data, while the others are parameters that needed to be estimated. But I am not familiar with anonymous functions.

Comment: @AngelChen Avoiding global variables is a universal programming heuristic in the same vein as not using goto type statements. By using a global in your case, you could feasibly alter the variables inside your fitness function which could cause unplanned behaviour in your main script. It's always better to rather scope your variables and pass them to functions as arguments rather than allowing the function to access something that really should be out of its scope. Don't forget to [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped.